# Concatenate Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

BizTable

```
ID          From Store      To Store        Quantity
01020405    401              402             5
01020405    499              406             6
01020405    401              418             15
01020405    403              402             10
01020405    402              403             20
01020405    402              406             10
01020405    406              403             2
```

My aim is to write a query that would show  The SUMMARY quantity going  OUT for each PART for  Each  row From BizTable above AND concatenate Stores  it is going TO in the string, something like the table below

```
ID          Store_OUT           SUM_Quantity      
01020405    401 -  402,418          20
01020405    402 -  403,406          30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE TESTXML
(
ID VARCHAR(20),
FromStore  VARCHAR(20),
ToStore  VARCHAR(20),
Quantity INT
)
INSERT INTO TESTXML
VALUES( '01020405','401','402',5),
( '01020405','499','406',6),
( '01020405','401','418',15),
( '01020405','403','402',10),
( '01020405','402','403',20),
( '01020405','402','406',10),
( '01020405','406','403',2)
```

Now try this

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
    ID,
    FromStore,
    ToStore,
    STORE_OUT = 
    (
        SELECT [text()] = A.ToStore + ','
        FROM TestXml A
        WHERE A.FromStore = B.FromStore
        ORDER BY A.ToStore
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    FROM TestXml B
) 
,BTE AS
(
    SELECT X.ID, X.FromStore, X.FromStore+' - '+X.STORE_OUT AS STORE_OUT , Y.Quantity 
    FROM CTE X
    JOIN TestXml Y ON X.ID = Y.ID AND X.FromStore = Y.FromStore AND X.ToStore = Y.ToStore
)
SELECT ID, LEFT(STORE_OUT, (LEN(STORE_OUT) - 1)) AS Store_Out, SUM(Quantity) AS  SUM_Quantity
FROM BTE
GROUP BY ID, STORE_OUT
```

You will get result as following

```
ID          Store_Out       Sum_Quantity
01020405    401 - 402,418   20
01020405    402 - 403,406   30
01020405    403 - 402       10
01020405    406 - 403       2
01020405    499 - 406       6
```

Comment: Great @Tanjim Rahman. It works perfectly well. I appreciate your imput.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT id, CONCAT(FROM_store,' - ',`to_store`) AS store_out, 
 SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity  
 FROM biztable 
 GROUP BY id , from_store, to_store
 ORDER BY id , from_store, to_store;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @J.Zend.

I missed the to_store column. Here is the correct query:

```
 SELECT id, CONCAT(FROM_store,' - ',`to_store`) AS store_out, 
        SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity  
 FROM biztable 
 GROUP BY id , from_store, to_store
 ORDER BY id , from_store, to_store;
```

There is ONE concern. The WHS-OUT column is not adding ALL the to_stores in the concatenation result as shown in the example. This query is using only one store.